# MP4 - get current subtitle text

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, srt

I'm trying to find a way to grab the current subtitle in an MP4 file. I see that `ffmpeg` can extract all subtitles into an .srt file, but it would be useful for me to just grab the current subtitle based on the current timestamp of a video being played. Especially useful if it can be done with python. This would be akin to `opencv` and `moviepy`, where I can extract the current frame as an image based on the current timestamp of the video.

I see a lot of libraries that work with subtitle .srt files (e.g. pysrt) but none that access individual subtitles from a playng mp4 file.

Comment: What is being used to play the file?

Comment: I generally use opencv or moviepy. They both allow me to iterate through the frames in the file. But I'm open to any tool as long as it gives me each frame (as an image) and the current subtitle.